# Recursive SQL question

Tags: sql, parent, categories

I need to find all the categories on the current level or below that have items, or have subcategories with items.
Categories have CategoryID, ParentCategoryID.
Items have a CategoryID.

I have most of the solution using a stored procedure:

```
AS   
WITH get_cat_hier   
AS  
(  

Select e.CategoryID, e.ParentCategoryID, From Categories AS e  
    where e.ParentCategoryId = @ParentCategoryId   
    union ALL  
    Select e.CategoryID, e.ParentCategoryID, From Categories e  
    inner join get_cat_hier AS ecte on ecte.CategoryID = e.ParentCategoryID  
        )  

select DISTINCT e.CategoryID from Categories as e   
 inner join items as item on (item.CategoryID = e.CategoryID) -- *******Problem*****  
where   
  (e.CategoryID in (select CategoryID FROM get_cat_hier AS CategoryID)

)
```

Unfortunately, this returns only the categories with items, and not categories with sub-categories with items. I need to replace the "`item.CategoryID = e.CategoryID`" with a recursive call somehow.

Comment: highlight your code, then click the `{}` button

Comment: Thanks for the formatting help! It looks much better.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is a new solution or one that is in development.  Doing this type of reporting is much much easier if you use nested sets to represent hierarchies.  Joe Celko has some great articles on this topic.

I did request tracking system a number of years ago where there was a deep hierarchy for the chain of command.  The reporting had to be for an individual and all their subordinates.

You should consider using nested sets and not using a parent pointer system.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

Comment: Great advice. See also http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html

Comment: Thanks for the advice,
However, I'm adding a small feature to an established program, and I can't justify changing the hierarchy scheme just for this..

Answer (score 0):

1. Take out your where clause (I don't think it is needed)
2. Leave your item join and then also join to the get_cat_heir between your item table and categories table.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the CTE's anchor member that causes the wrong result set.

Its WHERE clause should actually be `where e.CategoryId = @ParentCategoryId`.

Comment: That would only "raise" the results one level. So if we had   
C1, parent of C2 parent of C3. Passing it C1 - my code would return C2 and C3 (if it worked...). Your change would also return C1.